# Execute Shortcode in Textfile

Tags: php, shortcode

I´ve tried everything I know (include file, file_get_contents, "IncludeMe"-Plugin and others) to execute a shortcode within a textfile, but it didn´t work.

So here is the problem detailed and I hope somebody could help me: I´m taking different rows of post_content from a textfile this way:

```
$text = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'wptext/more_text.txt'; 
$texto = file($text); 

global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
$pm_row = get_post_meta($postid, 'pm_row', true);

global $wp_query; 
echo $texto[$pm_row];
```

It works so far, but in some of those rows are different shortcodes embedded. They don´t work and were always shown as plain text instead, although they are all functionel - outside of this textfile.

What am I missing?

Any hints for this?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of `more_text.txt`?

Comment: Surely:
Lorem ipsum dolor [KEY_SHORTY] sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut 
labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. [CATS_SHORTY] At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores 
et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor 
sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy [PROD_SHORTY] eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore 
magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd

Comment: `echo do_shortcode($texto[$pm_row]);`?

Comment: The reason the shortcodes aren't working is that they should be executed by [do_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) in order to be properly rendered. Maybe the suggestion by @kero should do the trick. As in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/), even if there are no shortcode tags defined, then the content will be returned without any filtering.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. No, "echo do_shortcode" doesn´t work - I´ve already tried it with working shortcodes - outside of those textfiles (= no problem). "$texto[$pm_row]" doesn´t work in this case, because I there is also a "$texto_2", "$texto_3"...... and I´m using "$pm_row"  also as $pm_row+1, $pm_row+2.....

Comment: sry...should be "....because there is also a "$texto_2", "$texto_3"..."

Comment: So...I need to execute the shortcodes to get all this background info from postmeta entries, I think.

Comment: @kero: Meanwhile I rethougt your suggestion and found an error in reasoning: If I say "echo $texto[$pm_row]" then this is only for choosing the desired row. The shortcode is already embedded in this row and has to be executed, so: This has nothing to do with the selection "$texto[$pm_row]"

Comment: @NinjaPopeye I don't understand your reasoning. Even you have multiple parts that all get concatenated to a new string, running it through `do_shortcode()` should give the desired result. If this doesn't properly work, you might need to set the global `$post` object to make WP think it is inside a loop

Comment: @kero: thanks for your answer. No, "global $post;" also didn´t work, either nothing changed or there was no content anymore.

Comment: Could it be a problem that this content belongs to post_type "product" in woocommerce? Is there any difference? I never thought so and btw: "$global product" also didn´t work...

Comment: how are those shortcodes defined? what is the exact full code of it? are yiou using a plugin?

Comment: @Michael: Nearby shortcode from "functions.php" - 

`function cats_shorty_shortcode($atts,$content=NULL){
ob_start();
global $product;
$data = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_dfrps_product', true );
$trash = array("\"", ">", "|", ";", ",");
$meta = get_post_meta($product->id, '_dfrps_product', TRUE );
    if (isset($meta['category'])) {
    echo str_ireplace($trash, " ", (wp_trim_words( $meta['category'], $num_words = 5, $more = "" ))) . '</b>';
    }
$return_val = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $return_val;
}
add_shortcode('CATS_SHORTY', 'cats_shorty_shortcode');`

Comment: Update: I find out that this whole thing seems to be a general php-problem, because just a simple "<?php echo 'test'; ?>" didn´t work there.... Any hints for this?

Comment: use [`include`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [`require`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) properly, to execute PHP in the file. [`file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) will only read the raw content of the text file.

Comment: @Samuel Elh Thanks for your advice, but if I would do so, then I always got the whole content of the file at once. What I need is the opportunity to get one row and afterwards the next one, like so: "$texto[$pm_row]", "$texto[$pm_row+1]" and so on...